# Rare character with custom font in Action bar

Tags: android, text, fonts, android-actionbar

I have added a custom font to my app in `Action bar`. But it has a problem. When the text of the Action bar is longer than the Action bar space, it shows something like this:

**Text very longer...[]**

3 points and some cases a rare character to final.

Waht is the problem?

**BaseActivity**

`textoTitulo.setTypeface(Modulo.fontPrincipal(this));`

**fontPrincipal**

```
public static Typeface fontPrincipal(Context context) {

    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/principal.TTF");
    return font;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that your font contains a value for the `ZERO WIDTH NO BREAK-SPACE` character which is character number U+FEFF. Open the font in your editor and add a zero width character at this address and the odd [] should disappear.

On the other hand, if you do not want the text to be truncated at all, then set the width of the element to `match_parent` and it will expand to fit the text that you give it.

Comment: I dont know how to do it... can you help me most?

Comment: Have a look at http://fontforge.org/ it will be able to edit the font file and generate a new one with the missing characters, if that is the problem

Comment: I have found the character U+FEFF. How I draw zero width character?